# How to include mk file to SConstruct

Tags: makefile, scons

I have Scons file and i want to add some include mk files.

my SConstruct

```
env = Environment()

# include file path
env.Append(CPPPATH=[""])

# library file path
#env.Append(LIBPATH=["/usr/lib64/"])

# Linking Flags 
#env.Append(LINKFLAGS="")

# Compile Flags
env.Append(CCFLAGS="-g -Wall -std=c++0 -DHAVE_DPDK")

# library files
env.Append(LIBS=["boost_thread", "boost_filesystem", "boost_system", "boost_log", "boost_regex"])

# define
env.Append(CPPDEFINES=["USER_LITTLE_ENDIAN"])

# source file list for making
src_files = ,
    Glob(test.cpp"),
    ]

# build target file
env.Program(build/test", source=src_files)
```

and this is makefile that i want to add.

```
ifeq ($(RTE_SDK),)
RTE_SDK = $(HOME)/DPDK
RTE_TARGET = build
endif

# Default target, can be overridden by command line or environment
RTE_TARGET = build

include $(HOME)/DPDK/mk/rte.vars.mk

APP = custom2

SRCS-y := custom2.c

CFLAGS += -g -DHAVE_DPDK

include $(HOME)/DPDK/mk/rte.extapp.mk
```

How can i include mk file on scons?

and how to set RTE_SDK = $(HOME)/DPDK on scons?

Thanks.

---

EDIT.

Or I try to find any ways, can compile DPDK with scons.

Comment: You can always just have a command to run make in that directory as long as you specify target(s) for such build and source(s). It should work. Otherwise you'll have to convert the build makefiles to SConscripts.

Answer (score 0):

Have at Tungsten Fabric/Contrail vrouter or just look here:
https://github.com/Juniper/contrail-vrouter/blob/master/SConscript
maybe that will help, they seem to be using SConscript and are basing their vrouter on DPDK.